# How do I modify the menubar in FireFox to display full page/tab title?

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-tabs

With FF 45.01 and previous versions for some time the page title is not displayed alongside of the menu bar, nor as part of it in Windows 10 and 8.1.  Exists the option to change the value, browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar to 'false' adding the page / tab title above the menubar thus removing more valuable space from vertical stack, undesired though simple to change, per this previous StackExchange question:  [How do I display the full page title in Firefox 29](https://superuser.com/questions/749395/how-do-i-display-the-full-title-bar-in-firefox-29)  This was asked a year ago, but this specifically was not answered.  Also asked and same answer as above here, [how-to-make-firefox-39-display-the-page-title-of-the-active-tab-in-the-window-titlebar?](https://superuser.com/questions/946796/how-to-make-firefox-39-display-the-page-title-of-the-active-tab-in-the-window-ti)  These two answers give the result in this image: [image of titlebar taking extra space above menubar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiBjt.png)

As FireFox is supposed the most configurable browser and having page titles appear on the menubar is default behavior once the menu is set to display in FF on Ubuntu (it is not displayed by default,) hopefully this is achievable on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, the “Personal Titlebar” extension will do what you want.  Instructions are on the extension’s homepage.  You can also drag a space to the menu bar ahead of the page title, which essential centers the title.